# Cloud Services/Architecture of a Multi-tenant Spring boot Project Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-eks, aws-codepipeline

Now I am working with our company product developed with spring boot , angular and PostgreSQL technologies where front end angular is communicating with 138 back end ReST API end points. And these 138 end points are from 35 different spring boot project. And all these end points need to separately deploy for 5 different tenant. Actually end point working is same.But databases are different for different tenant. And we decided to go with AWS cloud. And we are looking for cost effective deployment method from AWS.

**Our Current Development/Test strategy** - Current we are developing application(final stage of development) and testing our application using our On-premise server. Here we are using 5 ubuntu machines. And we created kubernetes cluster with 2 master nodes and 3 worker nodes.And from our SVN repository and Jenkins server we implemented CI/CD pipeline deployment to this 5 machines.

**Proposed Cloud Solution** - Now we are thinking with to use either EKS deployment method or any of CodeDeploy/CodePipeline method to implement this big project.

So by considering cost and control over infrastructure management which solution is better for my product? Now I am not that much experienced as solution architect and still in cloud learning curve. So can any one suggest/guide me to think properly to achieve my goal please?

**Company consideration**

1. Control over infrastructure
2. Cost effective
3. Easy management of aws services for multi-tenant deployment
4. Data security ( Installing database on ec2/ RDS)
5. Management of load balances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Control over infrastructure

it would be better to manage it on Github, Gitlab, and or AWS code build, or cloud build.

indeed AWS code build, and repo is great tools but again consider the limitation of extra users it allows only **5** users if your team is very big you might have to pay to compare to managing projects at the Github & GitLab level.

- Cost effective

EKS would be a good option compared to **ECS** or others as it has limitations of we can not run the **Daemon** **set** or **Privilege** PODs.

If you are looking for running everything On **POD** and auto-scalable with little less flexibility and don't want to manage much ECS also a good idea, but again you have to derive the capacity and compare both pricing **ECS** vs **EKS**.

**Note** : EKS will also charge the per hour charges **$0.10** for each cluster + worker nodes. it's not just worker nodes like in on-prem we run.

- Data security ( Installing database on ec2/ RDS)

RDS would be better as it's managed service compare to managing the EC2 and database performance and encryption etc.

it would be better to use RDS and EKS so the K8s service can connect to RDS easily on a private network.

RDS would be a cost-effective option considering the management of DB over EC2.

- Management of load balances

NLB or ALB will take care of that you can use any of them as per the requirement with EKS.

Cloud front could be also a great option with cloud storage to serve static assets, which will reduce calls, improve performance and be cost-effective also.